# Merge old and new table and fill values by date

Tags: pandas, merge, fill

I have **df1**:

| Date | Symbol | Time | Quantity | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-04 | AAPL | 09:54:48 | 11.0 | 115.97 |
| 2020-09-16 | AAPL | 09:30:02 | -11.0 | 115.33 |
| 2020-02-24 | AMBA | 09:30:02 | 22.0 | 64.24 |
| 2020-02-25 | AMBA | 14:01:28 | -22.0 | 62.64 |
| 2020-07-14 | AMGN | 09:30:01 | 5.0 | 243.90 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2020-12-08 | YUMC | 09:30:00 | -22.0 | 56.89 |
| 2020-11-18 | Z | 14:20:01 | 12.0 | 100.68 |
| 2020-11-20 | Z | 09:30:01 | -12.0 | 109.25 |
| 2020-09-04 | ZS | 09:45:24 | 9.0 | 135.94 |
| 2020-09-14 | ZS | 09:38:23 | -9.0 | 126.41 |

and **df2**:

|  | Date | USD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-02-01 | 22.702 |
| 3 | 2020-03-01 | 22.753 |
| 4 | 2020-06-01 | 22.601 |
| 5 | 2020-07-01 | 22.626 |
| 6 | 2020-08-01 | 22.739 |
| .. | ... | ... |
| 248 | 2020-12-23 | 21.681 |
| 249 | 2020-12-28 | 21.482 |
| 250 | 2020-12-29 | 21.462 |
| 251 | 2020-12-30 | 21.372 |
| 252 | 2020-12-31 | 21.387 |

I want to add a new column "USD" from df2 by date in df1.
Trying

```
new_df = (dane5.reset_index()
          .merge(kurz2,how='outer')
          .fillna(0)
          .set_index('Date'))

new_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
new_df= new_df[new_df['Symbol'] != 0]
print(new_df.head(50))
```

But I return zero value some rows:

| Date | Symbol | Time | Quantity | Price | USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | GL | 10:31:14 | 13.0 | 104.550000 | 0.000 |
| 2020-01-02 | ATEC | 13:35:04 | 211.0 | 6.860000 | 0.000 |
| 2020-01-03 | IOVA | 14:02:32 | 56.0 | 25.790000 | 0.000 |
| 2020-01-03 | TGNA | 09:30:00 | 90.0 | 16.080000 | 0.000 |
| 2020-01-03 | SCS | 09:30:01 | -70.0 | 20.100000 | 0.000 |
| 2020-01-03 | SKX | 09:30:09 | 34.0 | 41.940000 | 0.000 |
| 2020-01-06 | IOVA | 09:45:19 | -56.0 | 24.490000 | 24.163 |
| 2020-01-06 | GL | 09:30:02 | -13.0 | 103.430000 | 24.163 |
| 2020-01-06 | SKX | 15:55:15 | -34.0 | 43.900000 | 24.163 |
| 2020-01-07 | TGNA | 15:55:16 | -90.0 | 16.945000 | 23.810 |
| 2020-01-07 | MRTX | 09:46:18 | -13.0 | 101.290000 | 23.810 |
| 2020-01-07 | MRTX | 09:34:10 | 13.0 | 109.430000 | 23.810 |
| 2020-01-08 | ITCI | 09:30:01 | 49.0 | 27.640000 | 0.000 |

Could you some help me please?
Sorry my bad English language.

Comment: Reason is datetimes like `2020-01-02`not exist in `df1`, so are created missing values and then replaced by `0` in `.fillna(0)`. What should be there instead `0`?

Comment: Is exist in `df1`
`df1.loc[df1["Symbol"] == "GL"]`

|2020-01-02| GL |10:31:14 |13.0 |104.55|